# my cron command doesn’t work

Tags: command-line, cron

The commands that runs by `source` doesn’t work.

```
crontab -e


*/1 * * * * echo "1" > $HOME/cron && source $HOME/.zshrc && echo "2" >> $HOME/cron2 && source /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/.venv/bin/activate && echo "3" >> $HOME/cron && python /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/rememberMe/manage.py runcrons > /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/rememberMe/cronjobs.log && echo "4" >> $HOME/cron
```

Content of cron file is `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`source` is a `bash`-ism (or `zsh`-ism for that matter) whereas `cron` uses `sh` (`dash`) by default as the shell of choice.

So you need to use `.` instead of `source` to remain POSIX:

```
. "$HOME"/.zshrc
```

Or you can change the shell to any shell you want by using the `SHELL` variable of `crontab` e.g.:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
```

*You need to put this near the top of `crontab`, before any command entry.*

Following your example:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh

*/1 * * * * echo "1" > $HOME/cron && source $HOME/.zshrc && echo "2" >> $HOME/cron2 && source /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/.venv/bin/activate && echo "3" >> $HOME/cron && python /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/rememberMe/manage.py runcrons > /home/alux/gitHub/rememberMe/rememberMe/cronjobs.log && echo "4" >> $HOME/cron
```

And now you can stick with your original `source` approach.

This is the recommended approach for your case as you're `source`-ing `.zshrc`, presumably you have `zsh` specific declarations in there which won't work in `sh`.

If you don't want to set the `SHELL` variable, you can run the whole command as an argument to `zsh -c`, but this incurs careful quoting.

A safer approach would be to put the commands in a script, and run that as an executable with `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` shebang or as an argument to `zsh` (without making it executable).

---

As a side note, always quote your variable expansions unless you intentionally want to have word splitting and pathname expansion on them.

Comment: I changed it by but it dosent work yet :*/1 * * * * echo "1" > $HOME/cron && . "$HOME"/.bashrc && echo "2" >> $HOME/cron2

Comment: @ahmad Check my edits.

Comment: @steeldriver I Changed it to :*/1 * * * * SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh && echo "1" > $HOME/cron && source "$HOME"/.bashrc && echo "2" >> $HOME/cron2 , But it Dosent work yet :(

Comment: @ahmad You're supposed to put `SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh` at the top of your `crontab`, *and* keep the command as you've written in the question.

Comment: @steeldriver its now "SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
*/1 * * * * echo "1" > $HOME/cron && source $HOME/.bashrc && echo "2" > $HOME/cron2" But doset work. i dont know why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90162/discussion-between-ahmad-and-heemayl).

Comment: @ahmad No, what you're doing is wrong. Please check my edits carefully.